# Plot diagram in SAS

Tags: plot, sas, diagram

I should show in a diagram how the variable, avgflow, has evolved over time (1992-2006) for three groups of observations: i) intra-Euroland trade flows (EMU-EMU country pairs), ii) extra-Euroland trade flows (non EMU-non EMU country pairs), and iii) trade flows between EMU and non EMU country pairs. Keep the three groups constant over time, such that, e.g., Germany-France country pairs are classified as EMU-EMU for all years 1992-2006. Use 1999 as index 100.

I have created two dummy variable for the 3 groups of observations. The dummy variable, emu, is 1 when it is EMU-EMU country pairs and 0 when is non EMU-non EMU country pairs. And the dummy variable, emu1, is 1 when trade flows between EMU and non EMU country pairs.

I know I should use the PROC GPLOT, but I am not sure how to exactly use it for this case. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably off-topic for SO as asking for subjective opinion. That said, would suggest you start with sketching graphs with a pencil and decide what you want. (line graph with 3 lines?  grouped box chart??).

Comment: As Quentin suggested you really need to show the output you would like to get.  If you expect people to help, you should also provide some example data, and what code you have tried, or research that you have done.